# Stricter object literal assignment check on function return value?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, we get stricter object literal assignment checks when assigning to a variable or function argument. But how can I get the same strict checking on return type of a function?

```
type Sheet = { a?: number }
const sheet: Sheet = { a: 1, x: 1 } // => Error: "Object literal may only specify known properties"

type SheetFn = () => Sheet
const sheet2: SheetFn = () => ({ a: 1, x: 1 }) // => No Error!

// This has error, but I have to repeat the return type.
const sheet3: SheetFn = (): Sheet => ({ a: 1, x: 1 })
```

How can we enforce the strictness checks on return values?

Comment: By voting for [microsoft/TypeScript#12632](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12632) and annotating the return type the way you did in `sheet3` in the meantime?

Comment: Voted, does seem there's no way around being explicit about the return type.